# javascript math: what is the height of the image

Tags: javascript, math, percentage

What is the css height of the image if the width is for example: 3px?

original image height is 400px;
original image width is 800px;

what I've tried is:

convert the 3px to a percentage of the original image width:

```
function perwVal(v){
return 100 * v / iow; //img orig width
}

function perhVal(v){
return   v / 100 * ioh; // img original height
}

var imgwidthPerc = perwVal(3);
var imgheightPerc = perhVal(imgwidthPerc);

// not correct the height is off
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It should be `1.5px`, half the width.

Comment: Is JS even really needed for this? CSS has [`aspect-ratio`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio).

Answer (score 1):

You get the *ratio* of the width vs. height:

```
const ratio = originalWidth / originalHeight;
```

and then to find the width for a different height:

```
const newWidth = newHeight * ratio;
```

In your example:

```js
const originalHeight = 800;
const originalWidth = 400;
const ratio = originalWidth / originalHeight;
const newHeight = 3;
const newWidth = newHeight * ratio;
console.log(newWidth);
```

But note [Sebastian's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71195185/javascript-math-what-is-the-height-of-the-image/71195234#comment125847035_71195185) that you may not need it, you may be able to use CSS's [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio).

Comment: Thanks guys, this will work.. Its not for displaying an image as such, its predicting what the size of the image will be after a jquery animation is finished. So i can animate the image to the center of the screen. What i have setup now using css works great, but not on IOS. Hence this math issue.